# Styling ttk button borders

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, tcl, ttk

I'm trying to figure out how to style ttk buttons from Python ([ttk.Button](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html))
 on Linux, and right now I'm focusing on the border. All of the built-in themes (*alt*, *clam*, *classic*, and *default*) appear to use the *Button.border* element, but they list differing options and don't necessarily appear to support some listed options.

- *alt* lists *-background*, *-bordercolor*, *-default*, *-borderwidth*, and *-relief*. However, *-bordercolor* is ignored.
- *clam* lists *-bordercolor*, *-lightcolor*, *-darkcolor*, *-relief*, and *-borderwidth*. However, *-borderwidth* is ignored.
- *classic* lists *-background*, *-borderwidth*, *-relief*, and *-default*.
- *default* lists *-background*, *-borderwidth*, and *-relief*.

[image: Button borders across themes]

Why is it that for the *Button.border* element only *clam* supports *-bordercolor*, *-lightcolor*, and *-darkcolor*, and only the others support *-borderwidth*? Shouldn't all of the themes support all of those options?

I'm by no means proficient in reading Tcl, but I don't see anything in the ttk theme files ([altTheme.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/ttk/altTheme.tcl), [clamTheme.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/ttk/clamTheme.tcl), [classicTheme.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/ttk/classicTheme.tcl), [defaults.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/ttk/defaults.tcl)) that indicate the *Button.border* element is customized or any reference to it at all. There's only some *configure* and *map* calls for the *TButton* style.

---

This is the code I used to view the results above:

```
import pprint
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def theme_changed(theme):
    style.theme_use(theme)

    print(theme)
    pprint.pprint(style.layout('TButton'))
    pprint.pprint(style.element_options('Button.border'))

    style.configure(
        'Custom.TButton',
        background='#FFFFFF', # White
        bordercolor='#00FF00', # Green
        lightcolor='#FF0000', # Red
        darkcolor='#0000FF', # Blue
        borderwidth=4,
        foreground='#00FFFF', # Cyan
    )

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=sorted(style.theme_names()), state='readonly')
combo.set(style.theme_use())
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _e: theme_changed(combo.get()))
combo.pack()

theme_changed(style.theme_use())

button = ttk.Button(root, text="Normal Button")
button.pack()

button = ttk.Button(root, style="Custom.TButton", text="Custom Button")
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no standard for the various options/colors used internally by the themes.  This link has source [http://chiselapp.com/user/sgolovan/repository/ttk-themes/index] to various themes.